# How to Pass variables inside functions using new method

Tags: java, variables, web-crawler

I have this code in my web crawler project:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String frontierUrl = "http://www.cnn.com";

    //creates a new instance of class WebCrawler
    WebCrawler webCrawler = new WebCrawler();

    //Add the frontier url to the queue first
    webCrawler.enque(new LinkNode(frontierUrl));
    webCrawler.processQueue();

}

 void enque(LinkNode link){
    link.setEnqueTime(new Date());
    QUEUE.add(link);
}
```

And this is my LinkNode Class:

```
public class LinkNode implements Comparable<LinkNode>{
private String url;

public LinkNode(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}
```

It is working fine with no error. Am try to get understand how this line is working:

```
  webCrawler.enque(new LinkNode(frontierUrl));
```

So I do not want to pass the variable "frontierUrl" inside it directly and want to write this line in more details like this syntax form using "new" ..:

```
abc a = new abc ( );
```

Is there way to write this line in more details to get understand it well since am new in java ? or this is the formal way to pass it throw the function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is some ways. You need to understand about [Constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) which is a way to create your classes in Java.

Right now your code only allows to do:

```
LinkNode frl = new LinkNode(frontierUrl)
webCrawler.enque( frl ); //you are passing your LinkNode Instance
```

Another ways is changing your LinkNode Constructor and `url` variable scope:

```
public class LinkNode implements Comparable<LinkNode>{
   public String url;

   public LinkNode() {} // this is called default constructor and it is
                        // not needed at all
```

And use the code like:

```
LinkNode frl = new LinkNode()
frl.url = frontierUrl;
webCrawler.enque( frl ); //you are passing your LinkNode Instance
```

Another way is creating a setter method to your LinkNode url variable like

```
public class LinkNode implements Comparable<LinkNode>{
   private String url;

   public LinkNode() {}

   public void setUrl(String url){
        this.url = url;
   }
```

And use it as

```
LinkNode frl = new LinkNode()
frl.setUrl( frontierUrl );
webCrawler.enque( frl ); //you are passing your LinkNode Instance
```

This last way is better than the second because it is doing [Encapsulation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html) which is a good pratice on Java.

Answer (score 1):

- `new LinkNode(frontierUrl)` creates a new `LinkNode` object.
- `webCrawler.enque(new LinkNode(frontierUrl));` passes that created `LinkNode` object to the `enque` method.

---

Thus

```
webCrawler.enque(new LinkNode(frontierUrl));
```

is equivalent to

```
LinkNode link = new LinkNode(frontierUrl);
webCrawler.enque(link);
```

just without a redundant named variable.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do it in this way? it's nothing wrong to pass the frontierUrl in the LinkNode constructor.

But of course you can always do it like 
webCrawler.enque(new LinkNode(new String(frontierUrl));

but in this case you always create a new String object instead of getting it from the String Literal pool

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not need the created `LinkNode` object below in your main method your approach seems absolutly right for this example. You don't need to set a variable for the object if you only want to pass it to a method. It's more readable this way whit one ore a small amount of variables passed to the `LinkNode` constructor.